# d3-tip: the tooltip appears in the wrong place when I display more than one chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

When I use d3-tip in a page with more charts, the tooltip appears in a wrong place, at the left of the screen (like x=0), instead at the right of my horizontal bar chart.
I've tryied renaming variables, but nothing. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

```
    <!-- Chart1 ....... -->
    <section class="box-big-comment">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
            </div>
            <div id="ig2" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <script src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
        var m = [40, 10, 10, 100],
        w = 600 - m[1] - m[3],
        h = 600 - m[0] - m[2];

        var format = d3.format(".0%");

        var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
            y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], .1);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(-10).tickFormat(format),
            yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(10);

            var tip1 = d3.tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .offset([0, 20])

              .direction('e')
              .html(function(d) {
                return "Value:  <span style='color:steelblue'>" +"<b>"+ Math.round(d.value)+"%</b>" + "</span>";
              })

        var svg = d3.select("#ig2").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
            .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

            svg.call(tip1);

        d3.csv("data_a.csv", function(data) {

          // Parse numbers, and sort by value.
          data.forEach(function(d) { d.value = +d.value; });
          data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

          // Set the scale domain.
          x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
          y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));

          var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
              .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "bar")
              .on('mouseover', tip1.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip1.hide)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.name) + ")"; });

          bar.append("rect")
              .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
              .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

          /*bar.append("text")
              .attr("class", "value")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
              .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
              .attr("dx", -5)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
              .style("font-size", "12px")

              .text(function(d) { return format(d.value); });*/

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .style("font-size", "12px")
              .call(xAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("x", w )
                .attr("y", m[0]-75)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Value");

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .style("font-size", "12px")
              .call(yAxis);
        });

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}

    </script>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


<!-- Chart2 ....... -->
    <section class="box-big-comment">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
            </div>
            <div id="ig3" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <script src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
        var m = [40, 10, 10, 100],
        w = 600 - m[1] - m[3],
        h = 600 - m[0] - m[2];

        var format = d3.format(".0%");

        var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
            y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], .1);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(-10).tickFormat(format),
            yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(10);

            var tip2 = d3.tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .offset([0, 20])

              .direction('e')
              .html(function(d) {
                return "Value:  <span style='color:steelblue'>" +"<b>"+ Math.round(d.value)+"%</b>" + "</span>";
              })

        var svg2 = d3.select("#ig3").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
            .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

            svg.call(tip2);

        d3.csv("data_b.csv", function(data) {

          // Parse numbers, and sort by value.
          data.forEach(function(d) { d.value = +d.value; });
          data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

          // Set the scale domain.
          x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
          y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));

          var bar = svg2.selectAll("g.bar")
              .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "bar")
              .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip2.hide)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.name) + ")"; });

          bar.append("rect")
              .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
              .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

          /*bar.append("text")
              .attr("class", "value")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
              .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
              .attr("dx", -5)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
              .style("font-size", "12px")

              .text(function(d) { return format(d.value); });*/

          svg2.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .style("font-size", "12px")
              .call(xAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("x", w )
                .attr("y", m[0]-75)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Value");

          svg2.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .style("font-size", "12px")
              .call(yAxis);
        });

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}

    </script>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I started restructuring your code because cutting and pasting a block of code, is not a good way to duplicate a chart.  You are defining variables and functions that can be reused between charts.  Also put your html before the javascript instead of mixing it freely.  Not sure what fixed the issue, but it seems to work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qBNLIlJJjSHkWZDdNk5p?p=preview

Comment: Oh. Cool. Thanks Mark for your solution and suggestions. I am a newbie. I'd like to get the point I can lend a hand to others. I've just discovered the problem. I was loading twice d3-tip. Anyway your option looks cleaner and more efficient than mine. So, I'll include your ideas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just getting the two charts crossed:

The code above has svg.call(tip2) instead of svg2.call(tip2)

You also need to have different classes for tip1 and tip2 in `d3.tip().attr('class', 'tip-class')`

Here is the example from d3.js tooltip with two charts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .bar {
    fill: orange;
  }

  .bar:hover {
    fill: orangered ;
  }

  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }

  .d3-tip,
  .d3-tip-2 {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }

  /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
  .d3-tip:after,
  .d3-tip-2:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* Style northward tooltips differently */
  .d3-tip-2.n:after,
  .d3-tip.n:after {

    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

  var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

  var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
      return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
    })

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.call(tip);

  var data = [
    {letter: "A", frequency: .08167},
    {letter: "B", frequency: .01492},
    {letter: "C", frequency: .02780},
    {letter: "D", frequency: .04253},
    {letter: "E", frequency: .12702},
    {letter: "F", frequency: .02288},
    {letter: "G", frequency: .02022},
    {letter: "H", frequency: .06094},
    {letter: "I", frequency: .06973},
    {letter: "J", frequency: .00153},
    {letter: "K", frequency: .00747},
    {letter: "L", frequency: .04025},
    {letter: "M", frequency: .02517},
    {letter: "N", frequency: .06749}
  ];

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)


  var tip2 = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip-2')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
      return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
    })

  var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg2.call(tip2);

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

    svg2.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg2.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

    svg2.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip2.hide)

  function type(d) {
    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    return d;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi brenzy. Thanks for your answer. I changed it, but it doesn't work. :-/ Indeed, d3-tip works properly in one of the charts but not in the other.

Comment: @abd, it would be useful if you put up a working code snippet that displays the issue to debug.

Comment: Ok. Let me see how to do it brenzy. I am a newbie. Anyway, I've just discovered that it works correctly the last chart. I mean, if I display 2 charts, the first one has this problem, but the second one works properly. What is more, the problem in the 1st chart persists even when the 2nd one has not any d3-tip.

Comment: You also need to have different classes for tip1 and tip2 in d3.tip().attr('class', 'tip-class')

Comment: I got it. The problem: I was loading twice:   <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>